# 'count' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. use value instead

Tags: flutter, dart

i am trying to add cart Stepper counter to my app but got this error.

```
CartStepperInt(
  count: 1,
  didChangeCount: (value) {
    if (value < 1)
      {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Quantity can not be less than 1");
        return;

      }
    setState(() {
      value;
    },);

  },

  ),
```

count  word is {crossed} and the value of counter is not increasing.

Comment: whats CartStepperInt? are you referencing this package https://github.com/shirne/CartStepper/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looking at this package's code, it seems the developer simply deprecating the `count` parameter and want you to use the `value` parameter instead.
I didnt try but I think simply changing your

```
count: 1
```

to

```
value: 1
```

should eliminate this warning.

note that the 'value:' parameter and your '(value)' variable are a different variable and are not explicitly related